# I am trying to add multiple tagit fields dynamically but it is not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, tag-it

I have created a button to add new fields and the field I want to add is a tagit field on button click the data is apenned perfectly but the tagit feature is not working it is adding as blank ul. I do not know why it is not converting ul to a tagit field. Is there a way I can add tagit field dynamically?

I searched a lot on Google but nothing was found.

```js
var i = 1;
$('.tagWritting').each(function() {
  $(this).tagit({
    options: {
      fieldName: 'test_name' + i,
    }
  });
  i++;
});
$('.addField').on('click', function() {
  $('.tags').append('<ul class="tagWritting"></ul>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/aehlke/tag-it/master/js/tag-it.js"></script>
<link href="http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/css/jquery.tagit.css"rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="addField">Add New Field</a>
<div class="tags">
  <ul class="tagWritting"></ul>
  <ul class="tagWritting"></ul>
  <ul class="tagWritting"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add punctuation? Currently it is annoying to read. If you want others to help you, at least take some time to write correctly.

Comment: chekc now I hope this is not annouying now

Comment: The only thing you did is _remove_ the only period there was...............

Comment: sorry not getting you

Comment: You had _one_ dot in your very long paragraph of words you removed it but you shouldn't have removed it you should have added more dots and more commas because otherwise without any punctuation super long sentences like this are very annoying to read and if you want people to help you you should take some time to make readable questions and sentences because otherwise it's too long and too painful to read and understand nobody will andwer your question look at the other questions on this site and other sites and take some time to write correctly please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the tag is been created, appended and you are not running the `$().tagit()` to this new element

this part:

```
$('.tagWritting').each(function() {...});
```

needs to run **after** each Tag append

**Or**, after including a Tag, you can pick the last tag and do:

```
$(tagElement).tagit({...});
```

Something like:

```
var i = 0;
function addTagit(element){
  $(element).tagit({
    options: {
      fieldName: 'test_name' + i,
    }
  });
  i++;
}

$('.tagWritting').each(function(){
  addTagit(this);
});

$('.addField').on('click', function() {
  var tag = $('<ul class="tagWritting"></ul>');
  $('.tags').append(tag);
  addTagit(tag);
});
```

I didn't test the code, and I don't work with jQuery for years... but I think it can help you

Comment: I tried to add like this append('<script>$(tagElement).tagit({...});</scipt>') but javascript is ignoring the last dot

Comment: yes please I beleive in this way it will work because javascript will load and it will append and run javascript i was thinking same but according your idea this was making me an issue </script>